# Having a problem with build\nodes\runnodes

Tags: corda

I've been trying to build a CordApp and I downloaded the template from GitHub. The code that I've written is available on the following link:

https://github.com/shanmukhipriya99/taskcordapp

When I'm trying to run `gradlew.bat deployNodes` in the cmd terminal, this is what I got:

[gradlew.bat deployNodes]

[image]

Then when I run `build\nodes\runnodes` in the cmd terminal, this is what I got:

[build\nodes\runnodes]

[image]

Then I have three other terminal windows opening-up, they load the Corda part, show some red text that says something about the developer mode and all the node terminals get closed automatically before I'm able to read the entire text.

Can someone please help me in figuring out where I'm wrong!?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find any error logs in the build/nodes/<node_name>/logs folder.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also try to go to the individual node folder and try to run java -jar corda.jar command and try to check if it works.

Comment: Can you try and print that error caused by developer mode? The only thing that I could think off is that it's complaining that you didn't sign your contracts CorDapp and you didn't disable signing for your workflows Cordapp. If that's the case, have a look at [my article](https://blog.b9lab.com/why-you-need-to-sign-your-cordapps-and-how-to-do-it-464101e5ec71) about CorDapps signing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have had successfully started the nodes all in one terminal. I am not entirely sure, if this is the only issue, but I have seen this issue before. This is caused by lack of permission of the Terminal.

I have seen it happened for both Windows and Unix/Macos users. To resolve it you might need to grant the permission to Terminal manually.

If it still does not work out, I would actually suggest the alternative quick fix that Ashutosh mentioned in comment. Open a new tab and go to the root folder of each node`cd /build/nodes/XXX`, and start the node manually via `java -jar corda.jar`